# android - borders seems to be cut

Tags: android

I set the Root Layout background as black colour with corner radius and padding. I set the child layout background as white colour only so the corners seems to be removed. I mean it white colour as overlay of the black. I found one solution for this i.e., we should maintain one more xml like root layout background. Is there any good solution instead of this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/black_color" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: What is exactly your goal? the child must have round corners? can you post some picture of what you want and what you have?

Comment: I added picture. Please refer it. I don't want to cut the corners like image.

Comment: @naresh Can you post the Root Layout's background xml? (the one with rounded corners)

Comment: It well seems that the root is a grey background, then you have a child with a rounded rectangle and two children (top and bottom) inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another XML file for the white background and give corner top radius to left-right only. And apply this background to the child view.

Comment: Thanks. I already did it. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: No there is not. You need to create this either in XML or Java. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

try this or a modification of this.Just modify the lines and other things as you need it.I needed a black bar at the top.I just modified that to white for your use.But you will still ahve trim your image to be smaller than the overall border.
what if you put your image as

```
 android:scaleX="0.95"
 android:scaleY="0.95"
```

the drawable code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:bottom="40dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#7F7F7F" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="40dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#7F7F7F" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="40dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="24dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```